# Run a code when the war is deployed

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, jboss, listener

I need to know if I can run code from my war when the war was properly deployed.

Basically what I would like, if possible, have a listener that notifies me that the war was deployed. I'm open to any further complicated technical solution, they are welcome examples.

Application Server on which work is JBoss, it would be best if the proposed solution, if there is, it binds too not to JBoss.

Comment: What do you mean by "run a servlet"?

Comment: I mean that the listener who is notified if the war has been deployed can run code, it is a servlet or create and use a class, it is not important for me. The important thing for me is to receive this notification.